# Retrieve a String from DB using model method in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am developing a `Laravel 4` Application and I have a `Model` called Slideshow.
In this `Model` I have the following method:

```
public static function getFirstSlide($id){
        $slide = DB::select("SELECT link from slides WHERE slideshow_id = ?", array($id));
        $slide_url = $slide[0];
        var_dump($slide_url);
        echo $slide_url; die();
        return $slide_url;
    }
```

There is a `one to many` relationship between slideshows and slides. In the method I return the slides related to the slideshow and take the url of the first one which I would like to display as a thumbnail on the front-end. However every time I run the following code I get this error:

```
ErrorException thrown with message "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string (View: C:\wamp\www\xyz.tld\app\views\user\book.blade.php)"
```

When I do a `var_dump` I am told the data is a `String` so I am a little confused. On Front end I am trying to do this:

```
<img width="100%" height="100%" src="{{ url('img/slideshows/'.Slideshow::getFirstSlide($slideshow->id)) }}"/>
```

Comment: post your var_dump() please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
$slide_url = $slide[0]->link;
```

It's because `$slide[0]` returns something like this:

```
object(stdClass)[314]
public 'link' => ....
```

An `stdClass` object. So you should return string, like this:

```
public static function getFirstSlide($id){
    $slide = DB::select("SELECT link from slides WHERE slideshow_id = ?", array($id));
    // Probably check before returning it
    return $slide[0]->link;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the values of the array are the objects of stdClass if you want to get the link just use 
`$slide_url->link`.